# best way to evaluate react js app performance

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs, performance-testing

I have huge react app with 50 routes and almost 3000 components. now my question is, how can I check is my app performing well? which modules are taking time. total app's performance indicator how to identify.

what are the best tools in the market?

If you need more info what info you need, please mention in comment.

Comment: Start with Google's [Pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/).

Answer (score 1):

I assume we're speaking about benchmarking **the ReactJS performance**, not about the performance of your app in general, since your app would perform not optimal due to a ton of random reasons.

For an overview of your app's overall ReactJS performance, you could use [**Perf**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-addons-perf). Its a profiling tool, recommended in the [Performance tools page](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/perf.html) in ReactJS official docs. It's a good starting point.

Comment: I looked at it, this documentation is very helpful. ;-)  can you provide some other tool or testing framework that provides this facility. as well as some example if you can. thanks.

Comment: Great, I am glad I helped! There is a great post (listed in the docs too) that explains [how to benchmark react components with Perf](https://engineering.musefind.com/how-to-benchmark-react-components-the-quick-and-dirty-guide-f595baf1014c), examples included. If you need more specific example how to benchmark something specific, please post a question with a code example. Otherwise - I am afraid the topic is too broad to answer.

Comment: I don't have experience with any other tool or testing framework that provides this facility, but again - it depends for the specific use-case you want to benchmark. I would bet that Perf covers most of the common cases and if you don't want anything fancy - it will do the job for you ;-)

Comment: Actually for measure of performance i need to add full app here which is not possible, and with 1-2 route and small app which I can show here but validating performance with that doesn't make any sense. Anyway thanks for the answer. ;-)